# Как в jQuery выбрать нужный мне селектор при клике?

Tags: html, jquery

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number />
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="fun();>Принять</button>
</form>

function fun() {
      var str = document.getElementById("form").value;
      alert(str);
 }
```

Форм такого вида несколько, код у них абсолютно одинаковый. 
Как сделать так, что бы данные, которые я введу в поле `<input>`, при нажатии кнопки `<button>` передавались в одну функцию, и делала например `alert();`, выводя при этом разное содержимое. То есть ввел я во четвертое поле `2` - высветилось окошко с цифрой два.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что за четвёртое поле? Почему должен выводится разный `alert`? Если есть несколько одинаковых форм, то почему у форм есть `id`?

Comment: @Other неважно какое поле, речь о передаче значения обработчику. `id` это атрибут темы страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите пример. Вы это имеете в виду ?
Так же не понял зачем создавать формы, если в них все равно нет кнопки submit.

```js
var myHandler = function(text) {
  $('#result').text(text);
  // здесь был я .. или alert();
};

$('form button').click(function(e) {
  var text = $(this).siblings('input').val();
  myHandler(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" />
  <button class="btn" type="button">Принять</button>
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" />
  <button class="btn" type="button">Принять</button>
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" />
  <button class="btn" type="button">Принять</button>
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" />
  <button class="btn" type="button">Принять</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```